# What is meant by prepending "_" to variable?

Tags: variables, language-agnostic, naming-conventions

I noticed on several places within various languages (`C++`, `Java`, `Python`...)usage of `_variable` naming. What does this indicate?

Comment: In C it was used to declare system / internal variables. And the C programmers learnt Java and introduced it there as well though it is against java naming convention.

Comment: I suggest you specify a single language, or this may be multiple questions in one.

Comment: For Python, possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1301346/the-meaning-of-a-single-and-a-double-underscore-before-an-object-name-in-python

Comment: In C++ they are reserved keywords
http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/keyword
"begins with an underscore followed by an uppercase letter is always reserved to the implementation and should not be used as an identifier."

Answer (score 0):

in c or c++, _ is used start of variable name for some variable used in lib code.to prevent to same name found in your code and the lib.
I python _ is used for result that wasn't assigned to a variable .

Answer (score 0):

In Python:

```
_ = 1
(_-_) will now equal 0
```